# Посоветуйте layout для 2 колонок внутри FastAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout

Пытаюсь добавить список сыгранных игр к Android-приложению при помощи FastAdapter.

И функциональность вроде в порядке (загружаются очки, имена, фото игроков), но с внешним видом у меня проблемы:

[image: app screenshot]

Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, какой Android layout здесь бы подошел, для эстетичного показа данных 2х игроков, то есть чтобы было красиво слева - и равномерно и красиво справа (а не все сжато на левую сторону, как сейчас).

Вот мой текущий **item_finished_game.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="24dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/gid"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/finished" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="80dp"
            android:maxHeight="60dp"
            android:contentDescription="photo1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo2"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="80dp"
            android:maxHeight="60dp"
            android:contentDescription="photo2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/score1" />

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/score2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/given1" />

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/given2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/elo1" />

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/elo2" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

И вот моя модель **FinishedItem.java**:

```
public class FinishedItem extends AbstractItem<FinishedItem, FinishedItem.ViewHolder> {
    private final static String WON = "won";
    private final static String LOST = "lost";

    public long stamp;
    public int gid;
    public int score1;
    public int score2;
    public int elo1;
    public int elo2;
    public String state1;
    public String finished;
    public String given1;
    public String given2;
    public String photo1;
    public String photo2;

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.finished_item_id;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.item_finished_game;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder getViewHolder(@NonNull View v) {
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder extends FastAdapter.ViewHolder<FinishedItem> {
        private TextView mGid;
        private TextView mFinished;
        private TextView mScore1;
        private TextView mScore2;
        private TextView mGiven1;
        private TextView mGiven2;
        private TextView mElo1;
        private TextView mElo2;
        private ImageView mPhoto1;
        private ImageView mPhoto2;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mGid = view.findViewById(R.id.gid);
            mFinished = view.findViewById(R.id.finished);
            mScore1 = view.findViewById(R.id.score1);
            mScore2 = view.findViewById(R.id.score2);
            mGiven1 = view.findViewById(R.id.given1);
            mGiven2 = view.findViewById(R.id.given2);
            mElo1 = view.findViewById(R.id.elo1);
            mElo2 = view.findViewById(R.id.elo2);
            mPhoto1 = view.findViewById(R.id.photo1);
            mPhoto2 = view.findViewById(R.id.photo2);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(@NonNull FinishedItem item, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
            Resources r = mGid.getResources();

            String result = (WON.equals(item.state1) ? "Победа" : (LOST.equals(item.state1) ? "Поражение" : "Ничья"));

            mGid.setText(r.getString(R.string.str_game, item.gid));
            mFinished.setText(result + " / " + item.finished);
            mScore1.setText(r.getString(R.string.str_score, item.score1));
            mScore2.setText(r.getString(R.string.str_score, item.score2));
            mGiven1.setText(item.given1);
            mGiven2.setText(item.given2);
            mElo1.setText(String.valueOf(item.elo1));
            mElo2.setText(String.valueOf(item.elo2));

            if (URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(item.photo1)) {
                Picasso.with(mPhoto1.getContext()).load(item.photo1).into(mPhoto1);
            }

            if (URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(item.photo2)) {
                Picasso.with(mPhoto2.getContext()).load(item.photo2).into(mPhoto2);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void unbindView(@NonNull FinishedItem item) {
            mGid.setText(null);
            mFinished.setText(null);
            mScore1.setText(null);
            mScore2.setText(null);
            mGiven1.setText(null);
            mGiven2.setText(null);
            mElo1.setText(null);
            mElo2.setText(null);
            mPhoto1.setImageDrawable(null);
            mPhoto2.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**

Сделал, как предложено Георгием, при помощи ConstraintLayout, стало немного лучше:

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил вам использовать RecyclerView. Item верстать через ConstraintLayout. Получиться красиво и в коде, и внешне

Comment: как будто "красота" зависит от контейнера для верстки и ConstraintLayout имеет волшебную силу красоты результата. в любом подходящем контейнере можно сверстать, как задумано изначально, если понимаешь, что делаешь.

Comment: естественно зависит. зачем верстать все в допопных kayout? Так-то можно и простым <layout> нужный результат получить, но зачем это нужно?

Comment: нет никаких допотопных layout. каждому найдется применение в том или ином случае. ConstraintLayout заменяет RelativeLayout и является его намного более функциональной версией, но FrameLayout, LinearLayout, TableLayout имеют существенные преимущества перед ним в определенных кейсах и уж точно не допотопные. Ваш комментарий несет в себе смысл: зачем использовать допотопные средста передвижения, когда есть космические корабли. Конечно можно проехать небольшое растояние на велосипеде, но кому это нужно.

Comment: я обозначил простое и эффективное решение. если у вас другое мнение - добавляйте другой ответ.